# I can't access my database in localhost using xampp

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, localhost

i use Xampp and its not work on port 80 so i've changed it to 8080 and now apache and mysql works fine. my problem is that when im try to access to a database that i already created on phpmyadmin it wont work!

i use this code:

```
<?php
$requesturi = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$pos = strpos($requesturi, "uni");

$hostname_excal = "localhost:8080";
$database_excal = "my_database";
$username_excal = "root";
$password_excal = "123456";

$excal = mysql_pconnect($hostname_excal, $username_excal, $password_excal) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
?>
```

i try localhost for hostname and it doesnt work either.

i test this in my online host and [its works fine](http://blacks.ir/rest/pox/students.php). but i need this to work on localhost so i can present this in a meeting.

help me please.

Comment: `$hostname_excal = "localhost:3306";`

Comment: Xamp is just a package. You changed apache to listen on port 8080, mysql will still be listening on its default port, 3306, unless you changed something else

Comment: Also, why are you using the depreciated `mysql_pconnect`?

Comment: thanks steve, i change 8080 to 3306 and its working now.

Comment: i save this code in a php file and use it in my other files with require_once('../connecttodatabase.php'); to access my database

Comment: Well all `mysql_*` functions are depreciated, and `mysql_pconnect` also has a number of issues of its own. You would save yourself a lot of hassel by using `mysqli_*` functions or `PDO` instead. Or if you havent already built a lot of your app, use a nice microframework like fatfreephp or silex that has simple database wrappers included

Answer (score 1):

Did you changed the standart password? Xampp uses "" as initial password.

Try this:

```
$hostname_excal = "localhost";
$database_excal = "my_database";
$username_excal = "root";
$password_excal = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have miss spelled the php function it should be:

```
mysql_connect
```

you have

```
mysql_pconnect
```

also I strongly recooment you do not use mysql at all, it is varnible to injections, try learing mysli or pdo

Comment: `mysql_pconnect` is a for persistent connections. Its not a good idea to use it, but it does exist (its not a spelling mistake)

Comment: Ok agree jut checked never seen it or used it before thank you we all learn. Maybe @Hadi290 instead your current host name use '127.0.0.1'